# Image recognition with PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, ocr

I was wondering if there's any way of writing a PHP script that can read an image and look for specific elements in it. For example, the image will contain a list of names and for each name there will be a box where a specific character will be present. I want to be able to get all the names and to check for which names that specific character is present.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use an OCR class already made, like this one:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html

I've never used it but I think it could help you.