# Scrape a statistic from YouTube using PHP

Tags: php, xpath, curl, youtube, scrape

After struggling for 3 hours at trying to do this on my own, I have decided that it is either not possible or not possible for me to do on my own.  My question is as follows:

How can I scrape the numbers in the attached image using PHP to echo them in a webpage?

Image URL: http://gyazo.com/6ee1784a87dcdfb8cdf37e753d82411c

Please help.  I have tried almost everything, from using cURL, to using a regex, to trying an xPath.  Nothing has worked the right way.

I only want the numbers by themselves in order for them to be isolated, assigned to a variable, and then echoed elsewhere on the page.

Update:

http://youtube.com/exonianetwork - The URL I am trying to scrape.

```
/html/body[@class='date-20121213 en_US ltr   ytg-old-clearfix guide-feed-v2 site-left-aligned exp-new-site-width exp-watch7-comment-ui webkit webkit-537']/div[@id='body-container']/div[@id='page-container']/div[@id='page']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='branded-page-default-bg']/div[@id='branded-page-body-container']/div[@id='branded-page-body']/div[@class='channel-tab-content channel-layout-two-column selected   blogger-template ']/div[@class='tab-content-body']/div[@class='secondary-pane']/div[@class='user-profile channel-module yt-uix-c3-module-container ']/div[@class='module-view profile-view-module']/ul[@class='section'][1]/li[@class='user-profile-item '][1]/span[@class='value']
```

The xPath I tried, which didn't work for some unknown reason.  No exceptions or errors were thrown, and nothing was displayed.

Comment: What was your xPath query? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I've updated the original post with that information.

Comment: Image <--> image recognition software. The SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822380/image-recognition-with-php) suggests a PHP tool that might work.

Comment: I don't want the numbers from the image.  I want the numbers from the webpage, the image was merely to be used as a reference for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a simple XPath would be easier to manipulate and debug.

Here's a [Short Self-Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) (watch for the space at the end of the `class` name):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?
$url = "http://youtube.com/exonianetwork";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
if (!$html)
{
    print "Failed to fetch page. Error handling goes here";
}
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$profile_items = $xpath->query("//li[@class='user-profile-item ']/span[@class='value']");

if ($profile_items->length === 0) {
    print "No values found\n";
} else {
    foreach ($profile_items as $profile_item) {
        printf("%s\n", $profile_item->textContent);
    }
}

?>
```

### Execute:

```
% ./scrape.php

57
3,593
10,659,716
113,900
United Kingdom
```

Comment: PERFECT!  With just a little tweaking for my setup I've got it pushing to the end of an array so I can call the values individually :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try a regex again, this pattern should work:

```
!Network Videos:</span>\r\n +<span class=\"value\">([\d,]+).+Views:</span>\r\n +<span class=\"value\">([\d,]+).+Subscribers:</span>\r\n +<span class=\"value\">([\d,]+)!s
```

It captures the numbers with their embedded commas, which would then need to be stripped out.  I'm not familiar with PHP, so cannot give you more complete code