# OMR reading in PHP

Tags: php, omr

is there any way to read OMR sheet in php?
I want to check answer sheet on server which was uploaded to server by students in jpg or png format.
each sheet have 2 column and each column have 30 questions total questions is 60.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image recognition with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822380/image-recognition-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use it but you can try https://github.com/jansenfelipe/omr

You have to create a `.json` to target the coordinates(in the questionnaire sheet) in which there are the possible answers:

```
{
    "width": 600,
    "height": 800,
    "targets": [
      {
        "x1": 50,
        "y1": 43,
        "x2": 65,
        "y2": 57,
        "id": "Foo",
        "type": "rectangle",
        "tolerance": 60
      }
    ] 
}
```

The project uses the Imagick, a native php extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick API, to analyze the coordinates you gave inside `.json`.